# Android - Play Only Specific Range of Frames in VideoView?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Is there a way to only play a specific range of frames in an Android VideoView?

I'm trying to avoid creating a separate clip if it's possible to reuse the same clip for multiple use cases.

In certain situations, I only want to play frames 1-30, for example.

```
        _videoView.seekTo(0);
        _videoView.start();
        // Stop at frame 30
```

Comment: I could not find an answer to this, so I created a separate video clip of the range I need. Not the most elegant solution, but works until something better is found.